# query doesn't return expected results

Tags: mysql, subquery

This query doesn't return the expected results:

```
 select users.username,firstname,lastname,nickname,address,mobile,email,gender 
 from users
 where 
   username = (select userid from friends where friendid = 'ahmedhosni84')  OR
   (select friendid from friends where userid = 'ahmedhosni84');
```

I want to get all the information about the friends to a specified user name and get out only the first subquery and i want to get out the both sub queries

Answer (score 2):

You can't do queries like (and get the desired result)

```
username = 'X' or 'Y'
```

You either have to do

```
username = 'X' OR username = 'Y'
```

Or

```
username IN ('X', 'Y')
```

Comment: You can indeed do queries like that -- they just probably don't return the desired results.

Comment: i had this error when i used your answer  **Subquery returns more than 1 row**
this means that i will have errors if the user have more then one friend i used the two styles you told me about and still have this error not with all users of course

Comment: Change `username =` to `username IN` or add `LIMIT 1` to the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you're looking for is:

```
select users.username,firstname,lastname,nickname,address,mobile,email,gender 
 from users
 where 
 username IN (select userid from friends where friendid = 'ahmedhosni84')
 or
 username IN (select friendid from friends where userid = 'ahmedhosni84');
```

Edit: Using "IN" as these return more than one result.

Comment: i had this error when i used your answer  **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Comment: oh thanks a lot and i am testing , but it's a pleasure for me to know all of you .